# React Typescript input props for different types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working on some React code in Typescript and running into an issue with the types for it.

```js
interface StringCheckboxesProps {
  options: string[];
  value: string[];
  compareFn?: never;
}

interface ObjectCheckboxesProps<T extends object> {
  options: T[];
  value: T[];
  compareFn: (a: T, b: T) => boolean;
}

type CheckboxesProps<T extends string|object> = T extends object ? ObjectCheckboxesProps<T> : StringCheckboxesProps;
```

These types serve as the input props to a functional React component' What I basically want to achieve is that `T` should never contain a string in `ObjectCheckboxesProps`, and that I can do both of the following things:

```js
if (compareFn === undefined) {
  value // typescript should make sure this contains string[], currently not working
}

options.map(option => {
  if (typeof option === "string") {
    option // typescript should make sure this only contains string, not T
           // this will fail when using union types for me
  }
});
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to achieve my desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in typescript itself, as the above code works as expected since typescript 4.9.